# Creating / Mocking Android Context from a Java Application

Tags: java, android, mocking, mockito, android-context

I am trying to write a java program that uses some functions in an Android project.
I don't need an Android device or emulator, I just need to use some of the functions of the Android project.

The problem I'm running into is this: I'm trying to run something like this FROM JAVA:

```
AndroidProject testService = new AndroidProject(_context);
testService.start();
```

But "Context" is an Android thing, and I just can't figure out how to create one, or mock one, or get one from my Java class.

I'm not actually interested in the context, I'm really just interested in the `testService.start()`, but there is no () constructor for AndroidProject, just the `AndroidProject(context)` constructor is available.

I've tried

```
Context _context;
_context = null;
AndroidProject testService = new AndroidProject(_context);
testService.start();
```

But I get a `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!` error

I've also tried

```
MainActivity myMainActivity = new MainActivity();
Context _context;
_context = myMainActivity.getBaseContext(); // also tried getApplicationContext()
```

I've started looking into Mocking, but don't know if I'm making it too complicated or not...

- "***Mockito***" only mocks interfaces, and I want to mock the
  `MainActivity` class,
- "***Android Mock***" was too complicated, and I
  couldn't get my project to build with   `MainActivity myMockObject =
  AndroidMock.createMock(MainActivity.class);`
- "***Robotium***" seems like it's an Android application that tests an Android application.

**I just want to create some sort of Android dummy context and use it in my java application, to get to the other functions of that Android class...** is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android.jar` contains only **stub** implementation of the classes. It provides the means for you app to build, once you have your APK you must run it on an android device or emulator.

Even if you mock the components you need (i.e. `Context`) then you will reach the **stubs** somewhere. If you don't, then the code you are trying to run is not android dependant and you can probably factor it into an external `jar` that can be shared between your Java and Android projects.